# What if a table doesn't have a primary key

Tags: sqlite, database-design, foreign-keys

I have made a simple relation table. All consist of three tables:

1. Tables for storing personal data (Table_Person)
2. Table for storing address data (Table_Address)
3. Table to store the relationship between Table_Person and Table_Address (Table_PersonAddress).

What I want to ask is can I delete the primary key in `Table_PersonAddress` so that `Table_PersonAddress` doesn't have a primary key and all that's left is the `personID` and `addressID`?

Below is an example of a database relation that I made:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrbOW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete it, but my advice is to set a *composite* `PRIMARY KEY` for the 2 columns `personID` and `addressID` so each row is guaranteed to be `UNIQUE`.

```
PRIMARY KEY (personID, addressID)
```

and remember that in SQLite you always have the [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) column to use it as an id of the row if needed.
So create the table with this statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PersonAddress;
CREATE TABLE PersonAddress (
    personID    INTEGER,
    addressID   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(personID, addressID),
    FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person (personID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (addressID) REFERENCES Address (addressID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

One more thing: why did you define `personID` and `addressID` as `TEXT`?
Surely SQLite is not at all strict at data type definitions, but since the columns they reference are `INTEGER` they also should be `INTEGER`.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I will try your advice. and I define that data type as TEXT is because that is just an example, so I define the TEXT data type. What I want to ask is to correlate the above table that I already asked.

Comment: Yes, i have follow your advice and it's working. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any foreign key constraints setup on the junction table (that is, the third table which just stores relationships between people and their addresses), you *could* delete a person from the first table, while leaving behind the relationships in the third table.  However, just because you could do this, does not mean you would want to.  Most of the time, if you remove a person from the first table, you would also want to remove all of his relationships from the third table.  One way to do this in SQLite is by adding cascading delete constraints to the third table, when you create it:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_PersonAddress (
    ...
    CONSTRAINT fk_person
    FOREIGN KEY (personID)
    REFERENCES Table_Person (ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

You probably would also want to add a similar constraint for the address field in the third table, since removing an address also invalidates all relationships involving that address.

Note that SQLite does not allow a cascading delete constraint to be added to table which already exists.  You will have to recreate your tables somehow in order to add these constrains.